# Routing to separate modules?

Tags: angular

I want to create an angular app which routes to sub-apps.  Ive never created such a thing before.  Usually I create 1 application and implement routing for it.  I thought to myself, It could be a good idea to create my code more modular to separate topics, or apps under an umbrella.

Something akin to:

```
Main Site:
  - Site 1
  - Site 2
  - Site 3
```

The idea of subdomain'ing, is a different topic, but wanted to create 1 app umbrella, which then contained 3 Web Apps under it if possible.  im not sure if that would affect sub app routing or not.

I figured that since each App i create is within a Module, I could maybe have 4 Git Repos, 1 Umbrella, and 3 applications, then reference the 3 in the umbrella.  Given the native modularity with NgModule, it might be easier than I thought.

I have been looking online for a bit and have not figured out how to do this kind of thing.  Does anyone have feed back to accomplish this?

I am kind of thinking that in the Umbrella Module, I just import the other Modules, and then in the Router, I think I would likely use the Module Class as the point of reference.

If anyone has some guidance, I would love to learn and follow up with some detailed documentation, as it seems far more difficult than I thought.  Maybe I should just do subdomains for my server instead for organization, but i kinda like the idea of doing it from within angular.

I saw something similar to the following: https://appdividend.com/2018/12/14/angular-7-routing-and-sub-routing-tutorial-with-example/

The above have me create an app and then modules under it.  I was thinking that there was a way to Reference the sub modules as git repo's somewhere.  Similarly, This requires routing to be set up from the Top RoutingModule, which looks like it may ignore the routes of the child modules, plausibly breaking module flows.

This demo brings it even closer: https://medium.com/disney-streaming/combining-multiple-angular-applications-into-a-single-one-e87d530d6527

It works through creating the sub projects, routes, and then builds it all.  It is 1 step shy though for me, which is:  Can I separate the Sub app/modules to be from a different Git Repo, as opposed to being in this repo.  Part of me thinks that this would be accomplished from within our packages files which would import the applications, and then we could continue with development.

**EDIT**
someone wanted this closed because it is opinion based.  I did not think this is the case.  I am trying to essentially create an umbrella application which pulls and builds the sub applications.  The Umbrella application would update routing etc in accordance with some of the samples given i think.  I was just not sure how to do things like pull an independent repo and add it to this application etc.  I figured it would somehow have a gitignore as well because the files themselves are pulled through npm install or some other means.

Does anyone know how to do this?